# Use url_for to create link to an excel file in output folder

Tags: python, flask

I have one question about url_for [Unable to open files in python flask- 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143667/unable-to-open-files-in-python-flask-404-not-found). but was marked duplicate.

My requirement is very simple. To create an href link in the main page pointing to a file in the output folder. I tried almost all threads in SO for the answer seems not working for me. Im very new to python . Please help. Below is a sample code i have tried

```
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for,send_from_directory
    app = Flask(__name__)    

    @app.route('/main')
    def index():
        print 'test'
        return '''<a href="{{ url_for('uploaded_file', filename='a.txt') }}">Open file</a>'''

    @app.route('/out/<filename>')
    def uploaded_file(filename):
        print filename
        return send_from_directory('./out/',
                                   filename)
   @app.route('/out/<filename>')
   def uploaded_file2(filename):
      print filename
      return './out/'+filename

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your app directory structure should be like this so this code would work. If the filename was not found in out folder then you will see "url not found":

```
app/
  app.py
  static/
        out/
           a.txt
  templates/
    index.html

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for,send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
        UPLOAD_FOLDER = "static/out/"
)

@app.route('/main')
def index():
    print ('test')
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/out/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    print (filename)
    return send_from_directory(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename)

@app.route('/showfilepath/<filename>')
def uploaded_file2(filename):
    print (filename)
    return app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] + filename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)

# index.html
<a href="{{url_for('uploaded_file', filename='a.txt')}}">open file</a>

# a.txt
hey there ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it worked. But does it not work if the contents of Index.html is put directly in the return value as `code`@app.route('/main')
def index():
    print( 'test')
    return '''<a href="{{url_for('uploaded_file', filename='a.txt')}}">open file</a>'''
    #return render_template('index.html')`code`

Comment: Also is it possible to pass the a href tag completely as a parameter?. html is written as is when i tried.

Comment: got it !! we can use {{ variable|safe }}  to accept the html in the parameter. safe keyword allows html tags